# Verify multiple-digit integer in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a small tokenizer program to identify each string inputs respectively. However when I tested it with multiple digit number say "256" it gives me a string token of [Number 2,Number 5,Number 6] which isn't what I expected.

```
import Data.Char
data Token = Number Integer
     deriving (Show, Eq)

tokenize :: String -> [Token]
tokenize (c:cs)
     | isDigit c = Number (read [c]) : tokenize cs
     | otherwise = error
```

How do I make `isDigit` work with integers greater than 9? (has 2 or more digits)

Comment: the way you wrote it will not compile - is `isDigit`the same as `tokenize`? Can you please give us your working code?

Comment: aside from my comment a simple `tokenize s = [Number $ read s]` will do the job for this part (if you expected `tokenize "256" = [Number 256]`

Comment: I just edited the code. Guess I'll have to get rid of the `tokenize cs` part

Answer (score 4):

This is a hint:

```
> import Data.Char
> span isDigit "123abc456"
("123","abc456")
```

`span isDigit` returns a pair: the longest prefix made by digits only, and the rest of the string.

Comment: Right but if I tried `123 + 456` wouldn't it become `[123 , +456]` ? since the plus size is taken as a string along with `456`

Comment: @Walle Yes. You still need some recursion as in your posted code, as well as handling `+` or the other non digit tokens you might have in your language.